# JAXB XML Parsing Problem

Tags: java, xml, parsing, jaxb, xml-parsing

I use JAXB to write my objects to XML File in Java. It writes successfully. I check XML file and all value are true. But when i want to read this XML file some elements values change. Have you got any idea?

My Table class has 2 instances which types are List of Rows(Row Class) and Type(from Type Class).

```
Table t = tester.readXML("tables/course.xml");

List<Row> rows = new LinkedList<Row>();
rows.addAll(t.getRows());

for(Row r : rows)
    System.out.println(r.getName() + " " + r.getType().getIsPrimary());
}
```

Here is the XML Reader methods:

```
public Table readObject(String filepath) throws JAXBException {

        JAXBContext jc = JAXBContext.newInstance(Table.class);
        Unmarshaller u = jc.createUnmarshaller();
        Table hw = (Table) u.unmarshal(new File(filepath));     
        return hw;
    }

public Table readXML(String file) {
    try {
        File f = new File(file);
        if(f.exists()) {
            Table t = new Table();
            t = readObject(file);
            return t;               
        }           
    } catch (JAXBException e) {         
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;
}
```

Comment: Could you post the readXML function?  Also, could you post the code that writes/marshals the XML?

Comment: What values has changed? Also, if you write the loaded XML back into file, does it become different from original XML?

Comment: Yes. If i write the loaded XML back into the file , it become different.

Comment: Could you also post the XML?  I would recommend editing your question instead of posting it as an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**@XmlElements**

The @XmlElements annotation is used to represent an XML schema choice structure.  So instead of:

```
@XmlElements(value = { @XmlElement(name ="row") })
private List<Row> rows = new LinkedList<Row>();
```

You only need:

```
@XmlElement(name ="row")
private List<Row> rows = new LinkedList<Row>();
```

- http://bdoughan.blogspot.com/2010/10/jaxb-and-xsd-choice-xmlelements.html

**@XmlElementWrapper**

If you want to have a grouping element ("rows") surrounding your "row" elements you could use the @XmlElementWrapper annotation:

```
@XmlElementWrapper
@XmlElement(name ="row")
private List<Row> rows = new LinkedList<Row>();
```

This will give you the XML:

```
<rows>
    <row>...</row>
    <row>...</row>
</rows>
```

- http://bdoughan.blogspot.com/2010/09/jaxb-collection-properties.html

Comment: Problem is caused by Type class, I think. Its some attributes change while reading from XML

Comment: Ok I correct the problem. I had mistakes about usage of XMLRootElement